# Gaussian processes can be completely defined by second order statistics

Tags: probability, statistics

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_process#:%7E:text=A%20key%20fact%20of%20Gaussian%20processes%20is%20that%20they%20can%20be%20completely%20defined%20by%20their%20second%2Dorder%20statistics.) it says that Gaussian processes can be completely defined by their second order statistics.

Can someone help me understand why this is true? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's basically the same idea as "there is only one Gaussian distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$."

Comment: @angryavian I understand that there is only one Gaussian distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, but that would translate to, in the multivariate case, there is only one Gaussian process with mean function $\mu$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$. But I do not understand how this is the same as saying there is only one Gaussian process with covariance matrix $\Sigma$.

Comment: On the Wikipedia page, the next sentence qualifies it with "Thus, if a Gaussian process is *assumed to have mean zero*, defining the covariance function completely defines the process' behavior." You are right that you need to know both the mean function and the covariance function to determine a Gaussian process.

Comment: @angryavian I see now, thanks for this. I was reading a paper on low rank approximation of covariance matrices for Gaussian process regression recently, and the paper restricts its methods to mean $0$ Gaussian processes. I was wondering if you think that the reason the Wiki article points this out and papers like this focus on mean $0$ Gaussian processes is just because it makes calculations easier to write out and computations faster when trying to produce numerical results?

Comment: @angryavian In an applied setting if you are modeling a process with Gaussian process regression, it would be unlikely that you are using a mean $0$ prior right?